# Zipping these two lists not doing what I want

Tags: python, zip

I have two data structures in the form of strings generated using for loops that print out like so:

one:

```
11111,
11111,
11111,
```

two:

```
22222,
22222,
22222,
```

I am then putting `one` and `two` into a couple of lists so I can zip them. I am also adding a '*' to denote a line break in the data

```
one   = [11111,'*',11111,'*',11111,'*',]
two   = [22222,'*',22222,'*',22222,'*',]

one = str(one)
two = str(two)

print("'*',".join([",".join(x) for x in zip(one.split(),two.split())]))
```

I want my final output to be as so:

```
11111,22222
11111,22222
11111,22222
```

However what I am actually getting with the above code is an output of:

```
[11111,,[22222,'*','*',,'*','*',11111,,22222,'*','*',,'*','*',11111,,22222,'*','*'],'*']
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `zip` and `join`  the lists, separate with a comma in the inner join and a newline in the outer:

```
one = "11111,11111,11111"

two = "22222,22222,22222"


one, two = one.split(","),two.split(",")
print("\n".join([",".join(x) for x in zip(one,two)]))
11111,22222
11111,22222
11111,22222
```

Comment: hi again. this did what I wanted for the example I gave above. What I'm building up to though is a solution that will zip things in a loop. so say for example you had variables one,two,three and four that wanted the final output to be like (sample line from it): 11111,22222,33333,44444. How could i do that? Can you zip more than two items at once or would I have to do it in a loop where I keep adding on one more thing to zip each time?

Comment: yes just pass all the lists to zip and do exactly the same with the code

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> str1 = '''11111,
... 11111,
... 11111,'''
>>> str2 = '''22222,
... 22222,
... 22222,'''
for y in [ ",".join(x) for x in zip(str1.strip(',').split(',\n'),str2.strip(',').split(',\n'))]:
...     print(y)
```

output:

```
11111,22222
11111,22222
11111,22222
```

use `strip` to remove extra comma at last then `split` and then `join`